# What does it mean in java "your data sharing between backend and frontend must be in JSON via REST APIs"

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, jax-rs

I came across a question which says that data sharing between backend and frontend must be done in JSON via Rest Api. Now, I am confused that what should I do?

Should, I make a Java Project with Jax-RS which will provide a set of Api and another Dynamic Web Project which will use the previous project to access the database?

I don't know if I can do both things in the same project.

Comment: "Front end" to me usually means web browser.  You'd better clarify with the folks who wrote that spec though.  A second server serving the "front end" but running JEE would potentially fit the bill as well.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How about just asking that?

Comment: @markspace Yes, I am actually talking about the jsp and web pages that will be shown in the user browser. That is why I am asking that is there a way that both things can be accomplish in the same project

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am trying to use the JAX-RS and a Spring based web application in a same project, but I am not getting that how I can accomplish that. I means using Spring will have its own controller and service layer while JAX-RS will have different API that will do the same thing. So, I am not getting how can I make them to work?

Comment: "Can" you do that?  Certainly.  It seems like an odd choice, I would verify carefully that this is what the customer actually wants.  As for "how" you do that just call a JAX-RS or -JS library like you mentioned.  What exact trouble do you have with doing that?

Comment: @markspace Let's say that I have a Spring based project and a Jax-Rs Api which is localhost:8080/doSomething. Now when I hit the submit button in the JSP it will take me to the Spring controller, from there I can easily to do the task by going to service layer and dao but what I don't understand is as the question says the data must be done in JSON via Rest Api. So, do I have to convert all of the form data in JSON and the call the Jax-Rs Api in the Spring controller? Or do I have to do something else.

Comment: You only need a REST API if you are using Javascript/AJAX to get your data in the frontend. You don't connect an MVC framework (Spring MVC) with a REST API (JAX-RS), if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: A JAX-RS application and a Spring application will be two different applications. They can be configured as two different servlets in the same project though. You can configure both in the web.xml. They will be separate and have no knowledge of each other, but still be in the same project.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks for the comment, I know I can configure them in the same project but the problem was how to make them work together. However, I was also thinking about the thing you just mentioned. Do you think that if I create a Jax-RS project with API and a simple Web page with Ajax and all to show data from the API. I mean the Web page will not be a part of any project it will just call the API from the AJAX

Comment: I don't know. You haven't answered the question "What are you trying to accomplish?" You said "I want to use JAX-RS and Spring app together". That's not  _WHAT_ you want to do, it's _HOW_ you want to do it (which really doesn't make much sense. So again, I'll ask "What are you trying to accomplish?"

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I got a question from a coding site that I have to create a Web Application that will show some data from the database. Now in their requirement they have written that "The data sharing between backend and frontend must be in JSON via REST APIs". So, I am confused what does they are trying to say with this statement. That is why I wrote in my question that do I have to make two separate projects and if I make one then How do I make them work together (Frontend and Backend).

Comment: Sounds like they just want you to create a HTML/Javascript based web app using a REST API backend. So do that. What you should do is just create the entire site using static data. Then when you're done with that create the REST API and use jQuery to get the data from the API. Or if you know a frontend framework like AngularJS, use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your REST APIs and also data accessing logic in one project. So your front end application will invoke the REST APIs which are nothing but methods and from those methods you can access the DAO classes. You can have a service layer through which you access the DAO classes instead of directly invoking the same.

Comment: But, I am still confuse how can I do that. For example, I created a web service with link localhost:8080/adduser. Now, I am using Spring with the project so, do I have to call this url or this web service through the controller of the Spring. I mean, if there is a form with action "AddUserToDatabase" then hitting it would take me to the Spring Controller class, so from there do I have call the localhost:8080/adduser web service?

Comment: You can refer https://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-rest-example-tutorial-spring-restful-web-services

Comment: Here in this example, they are using ready made data and using them in postman. I can do this with Jax-Rs as well. But the problem is the data has to come through a form and other than that, the response has to be shown in a human readable format not in JSON format.

Comment: You can convert your form data to json(key,value) so that it can be used at backend. Also,  when you get the data from the backend in JSON format convert it back to whatever form you want.